# DataTables - Tabletools undefined at postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatables

I'm developing an asp.net website with a datatable that holds some items. When I do a postback I get the following error:

> Warning: TableTools 2 requires DataTables 1.9.0 or newer - etc..

Console error:

> Cannot set property 'TableTools' of undefined

Now I'm not sure what's going on, I tried re-initialising it by putting it into a pageLoad javascript function but I got the same result. I also tried messing with the retrieve and destroy properties but that didn't help either.

My code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#datatable').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sUrl": languageUrl
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The loading order of your scripts should be 1. jQuery
2. DataTables
3. TableTools Can you confirm that ?

Comment: It was ordered correctly, but for some unknown reason the cms i am working it decided to re-order the scripts what caused the problem. Thanks for reminding me to check the order!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNN decided to change the order of the scripts at the postback, when i added a priority to the tabletools and datatable it worked.